# Create a structured array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, structure

I would like to create a dictionary in Python using numpy commands.

First I tried to define the structure and then to populate the array according to a number/case selected by the user. When I try to request one of the cases I get the following error (for case 1):

```
cannot copy sequence with size 3 to array axis with dimension 1
```

How can I fix my code in order to be able to store the data I want in my structure? Regardless of the case I select.

Here is my code:

```
# defining the structure
usgStruct = np.zeros(1,dtype = [("satNr",np.int),
                             ("satAzimuth", np.int),
                             ("satElevation", np.int),
                             ("scenarioEnv", np.str),
                             ("scenarioHead", np.int),
                             ("scenarioLen", np.int), 
                             ("speed", np.int)])

def case1(): 
   usgStruct["satNr"]        = 3
   usgStruct["satAzimuth"]   = [180, 200, 235]
   usgStruct["satElevation"] = [35, 25, 25]
   usgStruct["scenarioEnv"]  = ["S", "S", "S", "U", "U"]
   usgStruct["scenarioHead"] = [45, 280, 45, 120, 200]
   usgStruct["scenarioLen"]  = [2000, 500, 3000, 2000, 500]
   usgStruct["speed"]        = [15, 15, 15, 10, 10]
   return usgStruct


def case2(): 
   usgStruct["satNr"]          = 2
   usgStruct["satAzimuth"]     = [180, 225]
   usgStruct["satElevation"]   = [45, 30]
   usgStruct["scenarioEnv"]    = ["U", "U", "O", "O", "S", "S", "S"]
   usgStruct["scenarioHead"]   = [30, 65, 65, 80, 80, 60, 130]
   usgStruct["scenarioLen"]    = [300, 800, 2000, 1000, 700, 700, 300]
   usgStruct["speed"]          = [10, 10, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15]
   return usgStruct


def case3(): 
   usgStruct["satNr"]        = 2         
   usgStruct["satAzimuth"]   = [180, 225]
   usgStruct["satElevation"] = [35, 30]  
   usgStruct["scenarioEnv"]  = ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'O']                 
   usgStruct["scenarioHead"] = [90, 45, 120, 70, 45]       
   usgStruct["scenarioLen"]  = [1500, 500, 300, 2000, 3000] 
   usgStruct["speed"]        = [15, 15, 15, 15, 20]
   return usgStruct

# set up a dictionary of actions

scenarioGenerator = {
   "1": case1,
   "2": case2,
   "3": case3}

runscenGen = raw_input("Please enter a number from 1 to 7\n ")
scenarioGenerator.get(runscenGen,case3)()                       #  specify a   default: case3       

 print usgStruct
```

Comment: the problem is that the definition of the array in the beginning (dtype) does not comply with the kind of data you want to fill it. In particular, the dimensionality of your data cannot be ignored. See examples here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html

Comment: thanks for narrowing it down for me, I will have a look and try to understand.

Comment: it might also be important for you that you also have to define the lengths of the entries already at the creation of the zeros array. So the same array would not be suitable for the different cases you defined, since the lengths differ. It might be difficult to use structured arrays in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

print the initial `usgStruct` array:

```
In [329]: usgStruct
Out[329]: 
array([(0, 0, 0, '', 0, 0, 0)], 
      dtype=[('satNr', '<i4'), ('satAzimuth', '<i4'), ('satElevation', '<i4'), ('scenarioEnv', '<U'), ('scenarioHead', '<i4'), ('scenarioLen', '<i4'), ('speed', '<i4')])
```

Its data is 6 numbers and one character ('U' on my py3).  That's all it can hold.  It can't hold lists.

Even if you defined it to be size (3,)

```
In [331]: usgStruct
Out[331]: 
array([(0, 0, 0, '', 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, '', 0, 0, 0),
       (0, 0, 0, '', 0, 0, 0)], 
      dtype=[('satNr', '<i4'), ('satAzimuth', '<i4'), ('satElevation', '<i4'), ('scenarioEnv', '<U'), ('scenarioHead', '<i4'), ('scenarioLen', '<i4'), ('speed', '<i4')])
```

individual records are still this 7 element tuple.

You `case` data is entirely different.  Each case looks like a dictionary with list values.  Changing `case1` to produce and return a dictionary:

```
In [334]: def case1():
     ...:    usgStruct={} 
     ...:    usgStruct["satNr"]        = 3
     ...:    usgStruct["satAzimuth"]   = [180, 200, 235]
     ...:    usgStruct["satElevation"] = [35, 25, 25]
     ...:    usgStruct["scenarioEnv"]  = ["S", "S", "S", "U", "U"]
     ...:    usgStruct["scenarioHead"] = [45, 280, 45, 120, 200]
     ...:    usgStruct["scenarioLen"]  = [2000, 500, 3000, 2000, 500]
     ...:    usgStruct["speed"]        = [15, 15, 15, 10, 10]
     ...:    return usgStruct
     ...: 
In [335]: case1()
Out[335]: 
{'satAzimuth': [180, 200, 235],
 'satElevation': [35, 25, 25],
 'satNr': 3,
 'scenarioEnv': ['S', 'S', 'S', 'U', 'U'],
 'scenarioHead': [45, 280, 45, 120, 200],
 'scenarioLen': [2000, 500, 3000, 2000, 500],
 'speed': [15, 15, 15, 10, 10]}
```

Now `scenarioGenerator` would be a dictionary of dictionaries.